# SpringBoot CommandLineRunner run() method not being called

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm learning SpringBoot. My (trivial) problem is I can't get the run() method from the CommandLineRunner Interface to be called by SpringBoot.
I'm using Java 8 , Eclipse Oxygen ,Maven and i'm running my project as a "Spring Boot App".
Code is:

```
package com.clarivate.dataviewer;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DvMain implements CommandLineRunner{

static Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.debug("DS1A in main()");
    //SpringApplication.run(DvMain.class, args);
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(DvMain.class);
    //ConfigurableApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(DvMain.class, args);
    logger.debug("DS1B in main()");
    app.run(args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    // This does not get called
    logger.debug("DS4 this line is never printed");
}
}
```

The overridden run() method does not get called.
I've tried creating a separate class that implements CommandLineRunner but same problem. The console trace is:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/44/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/44/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.10.0/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
12:58:42.225 [main] DEBUG  - DS1A in main()
12:58:42.289 [main] DEBUG  - DS1B in main()

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.2.RELEASE)

2018-06-20 12:58:42.614  INFO 16924 --- [           main] com.clarivate.dataviewer.DvMain          : Starting DvMain on 44-TPD-A with PID 16924 (C:\workspace_oxyegen\dataviewer\target\classes started by 44 in C:\workspace_oxyegen\dataviewer)
2018-06-20 12:58:42.615  INFO 16924 --- [           main] com.clarivate.dataviewer.DvMain          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-06-20 12:58:42.655  INFO 16924 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6b4a4e18: startup date [Wed Jun 20 12:58:42 BST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-20 12:58:43.266  INFO 16924 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-06-20 12:58:43.279  INFO 16924 --- [           main] com.clarivate.dataviewer.DvMain          : Started DvMain in 0.988 seconds (JVM running for 1.684)
2018-06-20 12:58:43.294  INFO 16924 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6b4a4e18: startup date [Wed Jun 20 12:58:42 BST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-20 12:58:43.296  INFO 16924 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

I'm sure i've made a simple mistake but I just can't see it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Add `logging.level.root=debug` to your application.properties file.

By default Spring boot does not display debug level logging. The first debug messages are shown because they are called before your Spring application has started.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the call is coming to your run method. But doesn't log anything because there are couple of issues with your logger. You can use `System.out.println(...)` to confirm this.

1. Change your Logger declaration as below.

   ```
   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DvMain.class);
   ```
2. You are not using correct libraries. Use Logger from **slf4j** and not **log4j**

   ```
   import org.slf4j.Logger;
   import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
   ```

Comment: Both log4j methods work. If I add logging.level.root=DEBUG into application.properties the DS4 line is printed. It looks like the logging level is set during the boot phase, which makes sense, but the level was different at the DS1 lines to the DS4 line. Anyway, whatever the reason , thanks for the pointer

Comment: Springboot doesnt work well with log4j. You can search for articles on that. just type in google. :) cheers.

Comment: I think you're correct there. If I set logging.level.root=DEBUG then I get tons of junk printed to the console, which I don't get if I have no logging level set., so what then is the default logging level?, who knows.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-console-output

Comment: So the default level is info, but you can print some debug messages before the spring boot phase, just to confuse everyone, nice.

Answer (score -1):

That is because your DvMain class is not annotated itself as Spring context @Component, so spring can not find your pojo to execute the run method that you override.

To solve just add @Component to the class, and you will see the traces at log.

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` is composed of `@SpringBootConfiguration`, which is composed of `@Configuration`, which in turn is composed of `@Component`, so `DvMain` is actually a Spring component.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.